# How to pass Value from UIViewController to UIView?

Tags: iphone

i have creted a UIView Subclass:

```
@interface GraphClass : UIView
{
    NSString *str;
}
```

And i have assigned GraphClass: to a View of an UIViewController Class named:

```
@interface GraphViewController : UIViewController
{


}
```

Now i want to pass  NSString *amount,value from another UIViewController Class

```
@interface MonthsListController : UIViewController
{
}
in viewDIdLoad

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
GraphClass *graph = [[GraphClass alloc]init];

graph.str = @"abc";
```

But am getting NULL value if i print str Value in GraphClass

```
-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    NSLog(@"Amount is = %@",str);//NULL VAlue :(
}
}
```

Comment: Just [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%40property+and+%40synthesize) for `@property` and `@synthesize` keywords.

Comment: There are many ways you could do this. Try having `str` in your `AppDelegate`, so then you could save or print values easily. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Yeah Adil i have set Property also :(

Comment: @user1206790: did you `synthesize` that?

Comment: SEE GUYS My EXACT ISSUE is "I want to put graph using -(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect Method. But i want to pass Values of co-ordinates from other View Controller

Comment: Help me out with an Example if u have any TY

Comment: Yeah adil.. i did.. otherwise it ll show error

Comment: You need to initialize `GraphClass *graph` in your `.h`, then @property synthesis it. This should help

Comment: It might be an crazy idea, but maybe you should post the EXACT code that is causing your problems? ---- "I have a problem with the engine of my car" [5 minutes later] "Actually it's not a car it's an airplane." [another 5 minutes] "And I can't see the engine because the plane is on fire" [5 more minutes]. HELP I need answers fast. We are sinking fast!!11

Answer (score 2):

**MonthsListController.h**

```
#import GraphClass.h

GraphClass *graph;

@property(nonstatic,retain)GraphClass *graph;
```

**MonthsListController.m**

```
@synthesis graph;
```

**viewDidLoad**

```
self.graph= [[GraphClass alloc]init];
[self.graph str:@"xx"];
```

**-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect**

```
NSLog(@"%@",graph.str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "GraphClass.h"
```

// in UIViewController Class

```
GraphClass *graph = [[GraphClass alloc] init];

graph.recStr=Amount;

[self.view addSubview:graph];
```

// In GraphClass

```
@interface GraphClass : UIView
{
    NSString *recStr;
}

@propery (nonatomic,strong)  NSString *recStr;
```